# Final line: "...circumnavigated the Captain..." story id?

Tags: story-identification

IIRC, it seems to be a tale of a cabin boy aboard a spaceship (and I read that it was based on a very old dirty joke although there was no actual dirty joke aspect to this story itself). The final line implied that rather than the ship being a ship and the cabin boy a cabin boy the ship was a space-living life form and the cabin boy one of its larvae. I am looking for title.

Probably a "golden age" story like from 1940s, certainly no later than 1970.

Comment: The "joke" actually relates to an old dirty ditty called "Good Ship Venus".  I throw this out there in case the Venus angle has any relevance to the story being searched for.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt:: yes, the lyric is sort of a pun. i like the story much more than the ditty.

Comment: I looked up the lyrics to "The Good Ship Venus" (on my phone, not my work PC - yikes, that's pretty NSFW).  I learned the core of that song as "The North Atlantic Squadron" way back when (the 1970s).  Some of the lyrics overlap, some don't.  The cabin boy stanza is exactly what I remember (except for one word).  As far as I know, it dated to the convoys crossing between Halifax and the UK during WWII.  I also expect that the song predates that - in the version I know, there's at least one reference to a ship under sail.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's the 1951 story [Cabin Boy](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56215) by Damon Knight.

It ends

> In effect, Tommy had circumnavigated the skipper.

Comment: I don't _think_ that's an adaptation?

Comment: The Chris Elliot movie doesn't have any reference to the 1951 story, I'm guessing similarities are just coincidence.  That movie is awesome, "These pipes are clean!"

Comment: It sounds more like a "comedy" version of *Captains Courageous*